# Инсталляция Puppy Linux Slacko 5.3.1 на HD

Tags: linux

Я установил Линукс на диск, надо отредактировать файл menu.lst, но в указанном каталоге`/boot/grub/` его нет. Помогите найти и отредактировать. Петренко А.М.

Comment: Эти команды не работают,но я решил проблему:Menu>Setup>Grub4Dos bootloader config>Search only this drive or partition>ok>ok>ok>Edit 'menu.lst'>ok.На экран выводит menu.lst ишпаргалку что надо вставить.Петренко А.М.

Comment: Хочу ещё добавить.Установил Puppy,перестал запускаться Ubuntu.Переустановил Ubuntu,перестал запускаться Puppy (в меню загрузкистал обозначаться unnown Puppy),но я решил проблему:в меню загрузкинавести курсор на unnown Puppy,нажать "е" и удалить строку,начинающуюся с search,затем ctrl-x.Puppy запускается.Петренко А.М.

Answer (score 3):

Зависит от версии `grub`. в 1.x ветке конфиг и назывался `menu.lst`. в граб 2.x ветке может называться по другому, но в любом случае будет в `/boot` и т.д. Просмотри файлы на предмет похожести на конфиг по содержанию - найдешь точно)) их там не очень много)

Answer (score 2):

`find / -name` (имя файла без скобок) : команда осуществит поиск нужного вам файла по всей файловой структуре, включая все смонтированные диски (в том числе и сетевые) и отобразит полный путь к нему.

`find -x/ -name` (имя файла без скобок) : то же самое, но поиск будет осуществляться исключительно на загрузочном диске вашей системы.

`find . -name 'имя файла'` : (с сохранением указанного синтаксиса) - поиск будет осуществлен в текущем каталоге и всех его подкаталогах.

`find . -mtime` -(здесь нужная вам цифра, вводить без скобок) : эта команда, как и предыдущая, осуществляет поиск в текущем каталоге и всех его подкаталогах, но ее отличие в том, что указав, к примеру, цифру 3 (`find . -mtime -3`) команда выдаст вам все файлы, которые были изменены в течение последних трех дней. Указав 0, команда найдет только те файлы, дата которых была изменена.

Comment: еще есть gui утилитка:catfish,часто пользуюсь ей,очень удобная.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще этот файл menu.lst обычно находится в /boot/grub. Если его нет, то можно искать его по имени

```
locate menu.lst
```

или

```
find . -name menu.lst
```

Перед тем, как искать, возможно стоит выполнить update-grub.

Answer (score 1):

В `cgrub2` файл называется `"/boot/grub/grub.cfg"` или создаем файл со своим вариантом загрузки в `"/etc/grub.d/"`.

Comment: А про /etc/default/grub уже все всё забыли?

Comment: Спасибо за дополнение.